# How to determine whether the page is a login page?

Tags: php, curl

I'm writing a PHP script that searches and reads html content using cURL.

I want to determine from the content and/or response header whether the target page requires login to access.

I understand that normally, upon anonymously requesting the page, the server would redirect to a login page if required. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I have read around and got a few ideas:

1. search for `refresh` meta tag or when the http return code is 302, then check if it refers to a URI with `&action=login` (or similar)
2. search for login form in the body of the effective page. (I recognize that there could be content AND login form on the same page)

Are these methods valid and how accurate are these methods? What other techniques/signs can I use to identify/suggest login page? Or is this an impossible task to carry out aiming at 60-70% accuracy?

**Note**: I'm not trying to scrape, just finding out whether it's a login-required page.

The following is the relevant options, just for reference.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think your answer will vary greatly depending on the site you are trying to access. That said, you'll prolly have to do some preg_match statements to determine this based on specific data. A http code isn't concrete evidence of whether a page for logging in or not (any page can 302 for example).

Comment: Also, a lot of sites have login forms on many many many public pages these days. Those many pages aren't necessarily "the main login page".

Comment: @PiZzL3 - Yes I do recognize those issues. I suppose there are no easy way to confirm when content and login form are on the same page. Anyway, when you mentioned "specific data", what do you exactly refer to?

Comment: What I mean is each wesite is unique. So to determine if you're on a genuine login page, you'll have to have specifics about each site. You can't just make a single filter and expect it to work on everything. You'll have to know exactly what each site's login page is suppose to look like and build from that.

Comment: I understand that. The point of this question is to find out whether there are ways to easily cover as many sites as possible, which, as you said, there aren't. Sadly, my project is not site-specific and I don't have time to do one filter for each sites. Oh well, my tough luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for a form on the redirect target page with a `<input type='password'`

Comment: This will catch most login page re-directs, but there could be pages that get re-directed and have a login as part of the site, but still have some good content. For example sites that have a member login on the side, but has lots of public content that are built on some CMS which has some URL re-directs to have pretty URL names.

Comment: Some logins are post rendered through javascript after clicking a link too.

Comment: @PiZzL3 - Yeah but they still have a form

Comment: Actually I see what you are saying, but they shouldn't be on pages where you are redirected to log in.

Comment: @therealsix - You can't see the form if js renders it after the page loads. Pulling the page with PHP cURL will only get you the raw html + js/etc... none of it renders out. You could technically run across a site that's 100% js rendered. So if you pull it down with cURL, all you get is js and you don't know what page you're on or what's gonna render on it.

Comment: I'm not saying this is fool proof- it was just an idea. You could make the same argument for a form within an iframe. I still think that in most cases redirects for login will show the form pretty plainly.

Comment: This answer seems like a good idea. As for JS-generated and iframe form, I guess that will be too complicate to deal with, so I'm not going to try.

Comment: Yea, I agree, I was just adding to your answer in the comments.